# Filter number-series from IntegerField() of a Django model

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to query an **IntegerField()** of a Django Model within a view for a series of numbers?

Since I have some additional *or* filter conditions I would like to use with [Q()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects), and casting a string with [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) does not seem to be a good option in combination.

Something like this would be the desired behavior:

```
if request.POST.get('number', None):
    search_query = Q()
    search_query |= Q(product__contains=request.POST['number'])
    ...
items = Product.objects.filter(search_query)
```

A number like **123** should filter IDs like these: **123**, **1123**, **1001230**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to cast the field in your query, which requires an annotation:

```py
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

queryset = Product.objects
if request.POST.get('number', None):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        product_as_string=Cast('product', output_field=CharField())
    )
    search_query = Q()
    search_query |= Q(product_as_string__contains=request.POST['number'])
    ...
    
items = queryset.filter(search_query)
```